# Can you recommend a small camera bag to fit medium SLR, superzoom lens, and small flash?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-bag

I just ordered a D7000, the 18-200 Nikkor lens, and a SB-400 flash, and I'm now looking for a bag to carry just these items. I'd like an over-the-shoulder type.

Would this work? I don't know if the flash will fit anywhere in there though....
http://www.thinktankphoto.com/products/digital-holster-10-v2.aspx

Any other recommendations would be appreciated! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a [crumpler 5 million dollar home (aka - 5mdh)](http://www.crumpler.com/US/Camera-Bags/Camera-Bags/5-Million-Dollar-Home.html?LanguageCode=EN&SKU=MDH000-B00P50). It can fit a camera with lens on (can't go bigger than a 24-70mm f/2.8), extra lens and a flash. So it will fit your stuff.

It's also nice because it doesn't look like a camera bag and it's over the shoulder like you want.

Comment: i like this one... do they sell in stores or online only?

Comment: @Jon Erickson: I have seen it in stores... I actually tried it out in a store and then ordered it online later.

Comment: i just went ahead and ordered it online... (couldn't wait haha)... thanks for the suggestion... it looks like a great bag for what i'm looking for...

Comment: got the bag and I love it... ordered the Crumpler Disgrace neck strap too, much more comfy then the included nikon strap

Answer (score 4):

Lowepro Exchange Messenger
http://www.lowepro.com/exchange

Less nerdy and conspicuous than a holster.
Big enough for a decent walk-around setup.
Small enough to not be annoying.
Less than $30.

They don't offer too much padding, but protection isn't its primary purpose. I'm pretty sure your D7000 with the mounted 18-200 will fit vertically, leaving room for the flash and still another lens. A nice bag for carrying around a minimal setup.

Answer (score 3):

The bag looks to small to carry the camera and the flash. Maybe the flash could fit in the attachment bag seen on one of the pictures. But in the bag itself isn't enough space in my eyes.

I would go for a slightly bigger (wider) shoulder bag. Personally I like the [crumpler](http://www.crumpler.com) ones, because of their "civil" look.
But I'll strongly advise you to go into a shop and look at the bag of your choice in real. Because you can get the size of the bag just from the photo really wrong.

Comment: good suggestion... i probably will do that once the camera arrives... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have the ThinkTank Digital Holster 20 (a slightly larger version of the one you show) and when un-extended it can fit my 60D with Tamron 17-50 and the Vivitar 383 flash.  The flash is a bit tight; I can just barely fit it across the back of the camera in the bag.  I don't know the exact dimensions of your camera but it may be doable with the 20 but unlikely with the 10.

Extending the bottom however lets you move the camera down in the bag and might give you the space for the flash.  I don't like extending it; it makes the bag awkward to walk with though. The question then becomes if your flash is short enough to fit across the bag's width.

Answer (score 1):

For a single body and one or two lenses setup I really like the Lowepro's [Slingshot](http://www.lowepro.com/slingshot) bags.

Comment: +1 from me as this is what I have. Trouble is I still have not got the inside 100% to what I like!

Comment: I guess you never have the perfect bag, I ended up having a few diferent bags for diferent occasions.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought this case:

[image][image]

Here on Amazon.com: [Case Logic SLRC-201 SLR Zoom Holster](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TZUS98)

It literally showed up today and I'm pleased to report that I can carry my D7000 + 18-200 lens and my SB-800 just fine.  You need to put the speedlight in first, on the right side (because the camera is bigger on that side) and adjust the "Hammock" slightly to the left.  But once setup like that it works really well.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the line from kata. This [one](http://www.kata-bags.com/product.asp?Version=photo&p_Id=433) is nice cause you can pull out your camera and start shooting without taking it off. look at image number 4. I am waiting to go on vacation to get their [bumble bee](http://www.kata-bags.com/productFRM2HS.asp?p_Id=19804&Version=Photo) model. Its a lot smaller in size. Also, i just saw they have a new [bug](http://www.kata-bags.com/productFRM2HS.asp?p_Id=19803&Version=Photo) model that is small and may be nice as well.

Comment: I have the 3N1-33 (similar to your 1st link, but with a rear laptop compartment). This bag is waaay bigger than the one the OP linked to. Note that it has space to much more than a body with one lens and a flash. This also makes it bulky and not necessarily an all-around bag. The "sling" mode's practicality is limited when the bag is full with gear. The lack of chest strap is irritating. Contrary to the other two bags you link to, the waist strap is essential for this size and is standard with the 3N1. KATA makes high quality products, and if you find a bag that fits your needs, go for it.