# Bag: Which one between Crumpler 5-6MDH and ThinkTank Retrospective 10-20

Tags: camera-bag

I have read [This Crumpler post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8205/small-camera-bag-to-fit-d7000-18-200-nikkor-sb-400-flash) and [This ThinkTank post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/191/which-camera-bag-for-a-single-dslr-camera-plus-2-lenses) and I can't decide between the two of them. Can I have your opinion ? Any specific Pros and Cons ?

(I also read a lot of reviews, but the **opinion of current users matters more to me**. The best way would be to try them a lot, but I can't)

Comment: BTW, I went with the ThinkTank Retrospective 10. A-W-E-S-O-M-E !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThinkTank was started by a designer from LowePro, and caters to the needs of the pro-photographer. Their gear is extremely well designed, handles bad treatment, and will hold a lot more gear than the bags would seem to at first look.

I have never heard a bad comment about the company; To the contrary, they go way out of their way to make sure their customers are happy. I've heard of them sending out replacement bags because a zipper wasn't working right, and, when the customer got the original bag's zipper working they told him to keep the replacement. That is the way to get repeat business.

It's the only line I'd consider if I was in the market for new cases, but my hardshell cases aren't anywhere near wearing out. Rats! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I just received my Crumpler 5MDH and I love this bag, the neck strap is nice and thick, and the bag overall if very sturdy and supportive (I feel like I can swing it around and not worry about the protection of my D7000).

It has a nice zipper mesh compartment on the flap and a front compartment that can store an external hdd for example. It looks like it can hold 2 lenses + 1 flash but depending on which lenses you own it may not be able to (I own a 18-200 nikkor which is longer and a sb-400 flash, and plan to get a 35mm f/1.8 lens here soon which will fit)

But I have no experience with any other bag, this is my first DSLR and bag purchased.

I got mine on Amazon for $64, but the price went back up to the retail price ($82), not sure why.