# Looking for a DSLR bag with wallet for 7" Android tablet / 9" netbook (for on-the-go editing, backup pics/WiFi uploads)

Tags: camera-bag, backup, android, preview, tablet

I'm looking for a DSLR camera bag that has a large enough wallet to house a 7" tablet or even a 9" netbook.

I would like to carry a tablet or small notebook PC for making backup copies of the photos, some editing and upload to internet via WiFi. I have a Toshiba NB100 9" notebook PC but was also considering an Android 7" tablet like this:
http://www.ergoelectronics.com/products/7-gotab-android-4-tablet-gbt740m
(It has USB On-the-go/OTG host for plugging in SD card readers as well as its own microSD slot)

Alternatives to this workflow approach welcome. Though I am aware of Eye-Fi WiFi SD cards in cameras for transmitting photos but think this might be too basic and not flexible enough for my needs.

I already have this bag for my Nikon D3100 DSLR so would be looking for something similar but with a large enough wallet:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/DURAGADGET-Padded-Rucksack-Backpack-PowerShot/dp/B0030U0V0G/ref=sr_1_5?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1343910559&sr=1-5

Preference: The wallet should not obstruct getting the camera out.

Looked at some similar questions already:

- [Can you recommend a small camera bag to fit medium SLR, superzoom lens, and small flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8205/can-you-recommend-a-small-camera-bag-to-fit-medium-slr-superzoom-lens-and-smal)
- [What different styles of camera bags exist, and how are they different?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11854/what-different-styles-of-camera-bags-exist-and-how-are-they-different)

Answer (score 3):

Loewepro makes a messenger bag that might work for you:
[Loewepro Compuday150](http://products.lowepro.com/product/CompuDay-Photo%20150,2248.htm)
I own it and like it a lot.

There is also a similar backpack version.

Answer (score 3):

I've been loving my [ThinkTank Photo Retrospective](http://www.thinktankphoto.com/categories/shoulder-bags/retrospective.aspx) 10. One of the things it does well is fit my iPad. The iPad will fit easily in the front pocket, snugly in the back outside pocket, and tightly in the inside back pocket; none of which are in the way to get the camera in/out. There are several sizes; the 7 or 5 might be more appropriate for a small kit and 7" tablet.

Answer (score 3):

I got a Kata KT D-3N1-20 earlier this year, and I love it. Tried to find a good backpack with side opening for easy access and landed on the Kata.

They have different sizes with and without a pocket for laptop/tablet. Based on the bag you have now you might want to look at the [Kata 3N1-22](http://www.kata-bags.com/product/8374.85655.83708.0.0/KT+DL-3N1-22/_/3N1-22_DL_for_DSLR_wmid-range_zoom_lens+_3-4_lenses+flash) or maybe even the [3N1-33](http://www.kata-bags.com/product/8374.85655.83708.0.0/KT+DL-3N1-33/_/3N1-33_DL_for_DSLR_wlong-range_zoom_lens+_5-6_lenses+flash) (larger).

I also have an old [Lowepro CompuDaypack](http://products.lowepro.com/product/CompuDaypack,1922,16.htm), which isn't used any more. It fits a computer + camera equipment fine, but it's too difficult to extract the camera from it.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Lowepro Classified AW 250]

In the classified series lowepro has [this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/586033-REG/Lowepro_LP35305_PEU_Classified_250_AW_Pro.html) monster. I have it, I like it for a few reasons:

1) It carries quite a lot of gear.

2) The wallet part is nice, zippers closed, and is unobstructing/unobstructed by your gear.

3) It's fairly discreet(for such a huge bag).

4) The quality is very high(as with all the bags in this series).

5) It's not a backpack(I needed specifically a shoulder bag, as I was already carrying a backpack).

Negatives:

1) It's huge.

2) It's really big.

3) It doesn't have wheels.

4) It's a little expensive.

But if you are looking for something a little larger and with a great laptop/netbook sleeve, this easily satisfies the request.